# How do I install Audacious visualization plugin?

Tags: software-installation, audacious

https://pclinuxos.pkgs.org/rolling/pclinuxos-x86_64/audacious-plugin-visualizations-4.1-2pclos2021.x86_64.rpm.html is the plugin. But it is about how to install in Ubuntu which to me is quite difficult, please help!

Comment: rpm=redhat, not Ubuntu. Please find a .deb and you can use software center to install it.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is included or not in the plugins package but you can try. Install it with `sudo apt install audacious-plugins`

Comment: @Rob what is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ubuntu 21.04 and newer you can use `audacious-plugins` package from *universe* pocket. Install it with

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacious-plugins
```

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and older you have to add [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/apps) first, so install using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacious-plugins
```

After installation you should launch Audacious and visit Services → Plugins menu to enable needed plugins in Visualization section, drag them to needed locations to get something like shown below:

[image: Visualizations]

---

Technical details (if needed): the link in your question contains a [link to rpm-package](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/pclinuxos/pclinuxos/apt/pclinuxos/64bit/RPMS.x86_64/audacious-plugin-visualizations-4.1-2pclos2021.x86_64.rpm).
When downloaded and extracted, one can see its contents as follows:

```
usr/
└── lib64
    └── audacious
        └── Visualization
            ├── blur_scope-qt.so
            ├── blur_scope.so
            ├── cairo-spectrum.so
            ├── gl-spectrum-qt.so
            ├── qt-spectrum.so
            └── vumeter-qt.so
```

so the next step is to use package contents search on https://packages.ubuntu.com [for example for *vumeter-qt.so* library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=vumeter-qt). This clearly says that one needs to install `audacious-plugins` package.

Comment: That is great Norbert, again a good help.  I am just halfway there since I had to also clean the sources.list that had .rpm pointers inside, causing all kind of nastiness. So the work is done, but I don't see any plugins yet, probably has to do with you second part where this package is required. Will look into that tomorrow, cheers!